# Question on Bochner spaces: Convergence of the weak time derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, bochner-spaces

> Let $U$ be a $C^2-$compact manifold and consider two non negative
>   sequences $f_n,g_n$ such that
>
> - $f_n \overset * \to f$ weakly in $L^{\infty}(0,T;\mathcal M_{*}(U))$
> - $g_n \overset * \to g$ weakly in $\mathcal M([0,T] \times U)$
>
> If $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c([0,T],H^1_0(U))$ then can we deduce anything
>   for the convergence of: $\int_{0}^T (\int_{U} \phi )(\int_{U}
>  {\partial}_t f_n+n{\partial}_tg_n)$ ?

Note: $\mathcal M$ denotes the space of signed measures with finite mass.

*MY THOUGHTS:*

If instead I had $\int_{0}^T \int_{U} \phi ({\partial}_t f_n+n{\partial}_tg_n)$, I could deduce a convergence in the sense of distributions but now I have no clue how I should handle it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there really factor $n$ in front of $\partial_tg_n$? If yes, then the sequence in question might be unbounded...

Comment: @daw yes,unfortunately there is...